# jsPdf table - all table column not visible

Tags: vue.js, jspdf, export-to-pdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPdf to export table data as pdf file, I have about 50 columns in my table.
but i am not able to see all columns in pdf. only few col are visible rest seems out of page, but there is no scrollbar in pdf file.
please suggest how to get a horizontal scrollbar on pdf page.

Below is my code snippet :

```js
 exportPDF(myTableHeaders,myTableData) {
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.setFont("helvetica");
      pdf.setFontSize(6);
     ;
      let headerConfig = myTableHeaders.map((header) => ({
        name: header.fieldName,
        prompt: header.label,
        width: 30,
        align: "center",
        fontSize: 6,
        padding: 0,
      }));

      pdf.table(20, 30, myTableData, headerConfig);

      pdf.save("pdf.pdf");
    }
```

Below is snap :

[image]